# How to disable line break for these two images

Tags: css, responsive-design

I want to force the two images at the same row. 
(because it will line-break when the window width is not enough)

I want to auto resize the images when the window width is getting smaller. (keep them at the same row)

### This is expected result

[image]

Here's the DEMO page http://4am-lesson.com:3000/

Do not line break , the following is not as expected
[image]

Comment: seems no way without JS

Answer (score 0):

its easy to implement !! Just put those images in a class and using this code should do the work! (make sure you have enough room for two images to appear in grid)

```
.your_class { display:inline-block; }
```

Hope, I solve your problem ! If not please let me know.

Cheers,